# Tailwind Styles are apparently not getting applied in my Next.js Project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I was coding along a Next.js tutorial project and noticed that my project was quite off...I figured it was my tailwind styles that weren't getting applied for whatever reason, tried tweaking the 'tailwind.config.js' a bit but nothing seemed to work.

I then tried creating a new Next project entirely with `create-next-app@latest` and straight up ran it with `npm run dev` -- I left all the code unedited/as they came.

I was expecting to get something like this:
[The normal boilerplate "Get Started" page for Next.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4n6Y.png)

but I got this instead:
[How the default "Get Started" page for Next.js looks on my pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFtah.png).

So I'm kinda stumped at this point...I don't what else to do on my part.

Here's my 'tailwind.config.js' file:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'gradient-radial': 'radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
        'gradient-conic':
          'conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

My 'globals.css' file:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

:root {
  --foreground-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  --background-start-rgb: 214, 219, 220;
  --background-end-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :root {
    --foreground-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
    --background-start-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
    --background-end-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  }
}

body {
  color: rgb(var(--foreground-rgb));
  background: linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      transparent,
      rgb(var(--background-end-rgb))
    )
    rgb(var(--background-start-rgb));
}
```

and my 'package.json' file:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "20.4.5",
    "@types/react": "18.2.18",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "next": "13.4.12",
    "postcss": "8.4.27",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3",
    "typescript": "5.1.6"
  }
}
```

My 'layout.tsx' file:

```
import './globals.css'
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Please, show some code.

Answer (score 2):

- First check your `package.json` to see if `tailwindcss`, `postcss` and `autoprefixer` are installed.
  If not , let's install them :

```
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwindcss init -p
```

- Then check the paths in `content` in your `tailwin.config.js` and make sure they are like this :

```
content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
     ],
```

Or like this if you are using `src` directory:

```
content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
```

- Then add tailwind directives to your css file, usually `global.css` :

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

And now run `npm run dev`, hopefully everything thing should work as expected.

Comment: It's quite unfortunate that I've tried all of these and they all proved to be unsuccessful...

Comment: Yeah same, it's not working for me, any ideas why it wouldn't be loading?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 reasons why Tailwind styles might not be working. **The first thing you should check** is if the Tailwind style sheet is being included in the `<head>` of your page document.

**If the style sheet does not appear or is empty** on your website, then you should check:

Have you included the tailwind directives in your global.css file?

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**Are you running the tailwindcss watch process** to include used utility classes in the stylesheet?

```
yarn tailwindcss:build --watch
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I added all the dev dependencies to dependencies and it worked. Also, make sure global css is imported in layout.js

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/css-styling#global-styles

One step is missing: check out if you imported global styles in `app/layout.tsx` file